# Selenium script execution on Linux vm with Chrome (60 and above version), Firefox(50 or above), internet explorer

Tags: linux, selenium, virtual-machine, execution

While executing the script in linux vm, getting unsupported driver exception for chrome 60 version and firefox 52 version.

Comment: Can anyone suggest how to run selenium in linux vm with chrome browser?

Comment: Please post complete exception details

Comment: Caused by: net.thucydides.core.webdriver.UnsupportedDriverException -- this is the error i am getting while execution

Answer (score 0):

The unsupported driver exception suggests that the Selenium WebDriver version and the browser version are incompatible. You will need to either upgrade or downgrade the version of either Selenium WebDriver or your browser.

Comment: with selenium 2.53.1 web driver version in windows OS with chrome 62 & 2.33 chrome driver, firefox 51 & 0.14.0 gecko driver is working fine. But in Linux VM with the same version of browser getting unsupported exception.

Comment: Can you please suggest me the exact driver and browser's version for all browsers.